# Is there a way to force refresh Bundle Id list on iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

For two days, the list of Bundle Ids (App Ids) on iTunesConnect is not refreshing when a new App Id is setup in the Developer Portal.

Have tried using another browser, clearing history, and waiting overnight.

Anyone know a trick to getting iTunesConnect to refresh this list to the accurate one?

Answer (score 0):

Apple helped escalate this and it is fixed.

Seems like there is a way to 'force' a reload. Open a ticket. :-)